# How do we know index value of an element if same element used multiple times in multiple pages?

Tags: angular, npm, protractor

I would like to select an element in HTML page for testing using the protractor, that element used repeatedly in multiple HTML pages. Is that will be accessed using the index of that element? then how do we get an index of that element?

If I want to find an element that is used multiple times on one page, I can get it by

```
all(locator).get(index)
suppose that element is present at 119th index then 
all(locator).get(119)
```

which makes my code more fragile. So, is there any other way to access element?

Comment: Please show your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You should use it's parent or ancestor to narrow down the searching scope gradually.

example of element chain:

```
element(locator of parent1).
element(locator of parent2)...
element(locator of self)
// parent1 is ancestor of parent2, parent 2 is ancestor of self
```

example of locator expression:

```
element(by.css('parent1_locator parent2_locator ... self locator'))
element(by.xpath('//parent1_locator//parent2_locator ... //self locator'))
```